# "No capture devices are available" in mediaCapture.InitializeAsync

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Here's the code:

```
MediaCapture mediaCapture;
mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Speech });
```

the last line throws an exception:

> "No capture devices are available"

That is despite a microphone being connected. The microphone works with the built in Windows 10 Voice recorder app so I know it's fine.
The app has permission to use the microphone, and it is on in the app's settings.

So why do I get the error / How do I overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you specify `Micorphone` capabilities in `Package.appxmainfest`?
If does, it should work, but throw another exception.

`There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.`

Cause you need to set `StreamingCaptureMode`.

I have corrected your code, see below.

```
MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings 
{
    MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Speech,
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio
});
```

[image]

For more info about speech, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/speech-recognition).